# Data Binding (C# UWP)

Tags: c#, wordpress, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

Try to make Data Binding

Write this class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WooCommerceNET;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce;

namespace xBindDataMilano.Models
{

    public class Orders
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }


    }
    public class OrderManager
    {

        public static async Task<List<Orders>> GetOrders()
        {



            RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("http://simplegames.com.ua/wp-json/wc/v1/", "ck_9d64c027d2c5f81b8bed3342eeccc6d337be813d", "cs_60697b1e6cbdeb8d62d19e0765e339f8e3334754");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);
            //Get all products
            var orders = await wc.GetOrders();


            var order = new List<Orders>();
            order.Add(new Orders { Date = ""+ order[0], Name = ""+ orders[0].billing.first_name , Adress = ""+ orders[0].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[0].shipping.address_2 });
            order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + order[1], Name = "" + orders[1].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[1].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[1].shipping.address_2 });
            order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + order[2], Name = "" + orders[2].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[2].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[2].shipping.address_2 });
            order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + order[3], Name = "" + orders[3].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[3].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[3].shipping.address_2 });
            order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + order[4], Name = "" + orders[4].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[4].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[4].shipping.address_2 });

            return order;
        }


    }
```

This is xaml of where data need to be shown

```html
 <Page
    x:Class="Milano.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Milano"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="using:xBindDataMilano.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Orders" x:Key="BookDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Date}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{x:Bind Name }" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="10" Text="{x:Bind Adress}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="20">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Orders}" 
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True" 
                  ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BookDataTemplate}">
        </GridView>


        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
                   Name="ResultTextBlock" 
                   FontSize="24" 
                   Foreground="Red" 
                   FontWeight="Bold" 
                   Margin="0,20,0,0" />

</Grid>
</Page>
```

And there xaml.cs file

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using xBindDataMilano.Models;



namespace Milano
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class Test : Page
    {

        private List<Orders> Orders; 
        public Test()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            Disp();
        }

        public async void Disp() {

            Orders = await OrderManager.GetOrders();


        }

        private void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

When I compile I have this error:

[image: Error]

How I can solve this error.

About what index it is talking?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Did you debug the application? You should be able to answer your question with the help of debugger.

Comment: Yes. I debug. You can see error that debugger shows on screenshot @Reddy

Answer (score 2):

Remove order[0], order[1],... from below code. This should fix your problem.

```
 var order = new List<Orders>();
        order.Add(new Orders { Date = ""+ order[0], Name = ""+ orders[0].billing.first_name , Adress = ""+ orders[0].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[0].shipping.address_2 });
        order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + order[1], Name = "" + orders[1].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[1].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[1].shipping.address_2 });
        order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + order[2], Name = "" + orders[2].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[2].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[2].shipping.address_2 });
        order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + order[3], Name = "" + orders[3].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[3].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[3].shipping.address_2 });
        order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + order[4], Name = "" + orders[4].billing.first_name, Adress = "" + orders[4].shipping.address_1 + "                     " + orders[4].shipping.address_2 });
```

You are trying to access 0th element from Orders when there is no data in the collection.

Comment: I write orders[0].date_created, don't see this error. But my screen is white. How I can make it black?

Comment: How do you expect the screen to show a black when there is no data in your source? Make changes in your XAML accordingly.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;


public class Program
{
 public class Orders
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Adress { get; set; }


    }
 
 public static void Main()
 {
  var order = new List<Orders>();
            order.Add(new Orders { Date = "" + order[0].Date});
            order.Add(new Orders { Date = ""});

 }
}

This is not valid.

Comment: Why it's not valid? @Reddy

Comment: Iа you take a look you will see this using WooCommerceNET;
using WooCommerceNET.WooCommerce;

I have WooCommerce.NET plugin

and I wrote that I using orders[0] instead of order[0]


I don't have error anymore. But I have white screen

Comment: refer to https://dotnetfiddle.net/8q2UFN to find why it is not valid.
You cannt use a undeclared variable.

Comment: Anyway I found answer